# How to count rows called orders from the last 30 days and sum up the price of that order?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

The order table is made up of quantity, price, username and orderdate which is in datetime format.

An order is submitted from a cart page, if multiple items are submitted such as 8 monitors and 2 pcs. It will input those as two separate records.

### The goal: To multiply the quantity by the price for each record a user has, then to add those records up for the last 30 days.

Tried the below code to get the orders from the last 30 days which isnt working.

### edit: working code for getting orders from last 30 days

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` 
where orderdate between adddate(now(),-30) and now()
```

Honestly not sure where to start with the above sql statement, not sure where exactly the groupbys, count and sum() functions go since I am only starting with sql.

Comment: How is this not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below query

```
SELECT SUM(`price`) AS sum FROM orders
WHERE `orderdate` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW();
```

If you need to count row and sum the sales price

```
SELECT SUM(`price`) AS sum,COUNT(*) AS counter FROM orders
WHERE `orderdate` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW();
```

Alternatively, if you wanted these queries by username,

```
SELECT SUM(`price`) AS sum FROM orders
WHERE uname = 'test' and `orderdate` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW();

SELECT SUM(`price`) AS sum,COUNT(*) AS counter FROM orders
where uname = 'test' and `orderdate` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW();
```

Comment: This works perfectly except it doesnt multiply the quantity by the price.

Comment: @IanO'Loughlin use SUM(price*quantity)

Answer (score 0):

Be more explicit:

```
WHERE orderdate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

Or, because you probably do not care about the time component:

```
WHERE orderdate >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the "total order value" for the last 30 days, you need to calculate [`SUM()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) on `price*quantity`:

```
SELECT SUM(price*quantity) AS total_order_value 
FROM orders 
WHERE orderdate BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY and NOW()
```